# Can't store downloaded files in their concerning folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to download few document files (ending with .doc) from a webpage. The reason I do not wish to use `requests` or `urllib` module to download the files is because the website I'm currently palying with do not have any true url connected to each file. They are javascript encrypted. However, I've chosen a link within my script to mimic the same.

What my script does at this moment:

1. Create a master folder in the desktop
2. Create subfolders within the master folder taking the name of the files to be downloaded
3. Download files initiating click on their links and put the files in master folder. `(this is what I need rectified)`

> ***How can I modify my script to download the files initiating click on their links and put the downloaded files in their concerning folders?***

This is my try so far:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

link ='https://www.online-convert.com/file-format/doc' 

dirf = os.path.expanduser('~')
desk_location = dirf + r'\Desktop\file_folder'
if not os.path.exists(desk_location):os.mkdir(desk_location)

def download_files():
    driver.get(link)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href$='.doc']")[:2]:
        filename = item.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1]
        #creating new folder in accordance with filename to store the downloaded file in thier concerning folder
        folder_name = item.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        #set the new location of the folders to be created
        new_location = os.path.join(desk_location,folder_name)
        if not os.path.exists(new_location):os.mkdir(new_location)
        #set the location of the folders the downloaded files will be within
        file_location = os.path.join(new_location,filename)
        item.click()

        time_to_wait = 10
        time_counter = 0
        try:
            while not os.path.exists(file_location):
                time.sleep(1)
                time_counter += 1
                if time_counter > time_to_wait:break
        except Exception:pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory' : desk_location,
            'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1
        }
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    download_files()
```

The following image represents how the downloaded files are currently stored `(the files are outside of their concerning folders)`:

[image]

Comment: Which URL has the encrypted links? Testing the URL you have given obviously has no problems when used with `requests`.

Comment: Hi Martin, the [URL](https://aca6.accela.com/calcannabis/Login.aspx) I was talking about is login protected so I chose another url in my post to mimic the same by using selenium. If it were not for clicking the links to download, I could have handled the issue myself. Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to pull the href value from an element and use that to download a file, browsers need a real URL to be able to download a file, there is no "encrypted javascript" magic going on here.  The one problem you may have is that you need to be logged in.  In that case copy the session cookies and supply them to the request or urllibs libraries

Comment: Have a read of this, it may help (even though the code is Java) http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just added the the rename of the file to move it. So it'll work just as you have it, but then once it downloads the file, will move it to the correct path:

`os.rename(desk_location + '\\' + filename, file_location)`

Full Code:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

link ='https://www.online-convert.com/file-format/doc' 

dirf = os.path.expanduser('~')
desk_location = dirf + r'\Desktop\file_folder'
if not os.path.exists(desk_location):
    os.mkdir(desk_location)

def download_files():
    driver.get(link)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href$='.doc']")[:2]:
        filename = item.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1]
        #creating new folder in accordance with filename to store the downloaded file in thier concerning folder
        folder_name = item.get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
        #set the new location of the folders to be created
        new_location = os.path.join(desk_location,folder_name)
        if not os.path.exists(new_location):
            os.mkdir(new_location)
        #set the location of the folders the downloaded files will be within
        file_location = os.path.join(new_location,filename)
        item.click()

        time_to_wait = 10
        time_counter = 0

        try:
            while not os.path.exists(file_location):
                time.sleep(1)
                time_counter += 1
                if time_counter > time_to_wait:break
            os.rename(desk_location + '\\' + filename, file_location)
        except Exception:pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory' : desk_location,
            'profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads': 1
        }
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    download_files()
```

Comment: It's a nice solution to get things done @chitown88. It seems to be working in the right way. Let's wait few more days if anything more elegant comes along. Thanks.

Comment: the other 2 options I can think of: a) set the default directory within the download_files function. But then you need to initialize that chrome options each time. instead of just the once, or b) right click on the element and select save link as... But the problem with that is once you do a right click on the element, the rest is out of the realm of selenium, so you'd need to use something like pyautogui to press down, down, down, down, enter

Answer (score 0):

Use this code while declaring the Driver object (This is for Java, Python will also have a similar way to accomplish it) 
This will download the file to the specified location every time.

```
    //Create preference object
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String , Object>();   
    //Set Download path  
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory","C:\\Reports\\AutomaionDownloads");
        chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);    
        //Call the Chrome Driver
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html) library in Python 3 or the [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) library for Python 2 to handle paths. It gives you an object-oriented way to work with files and directories. Also it has `PurePath` object, which can work with paths without even touching the filesystem.